# Deny workitem workflow editing

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

We are using tfs 2013 update 4.

One of our colleagues downloaded TFS PowerTools by itself and started to edit workflow and fields of our projects. 
Is there any way to deny this functional for him?
Hi is not a project administrator, not TFS adminstrator. TFS powertools allows to change witd for all who can see the project.

Answer (score 2):

Set his **Manage Process Template** permission to **Deny**. This is a collection-level setting.

Comment: It was Inherited deny. but i noticed that his accoiunt in a group which is in a group Project Collection Administrators. Deleted him. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

They must have higher level permissions than you think.  Maybe an AD group they are a member of has been added in to Collection Admins or something like that?

[Customize a process template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243782(v=vs.120).aspx)

> "To download or upload process templates, you must either be a member
>   of the Project Collection Administrators group, or your Manage process
>   template permission must be set to Allow"

Download the sidekicks utility and you'll easily be able to see which permissions the user has.
[Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/)

If they are a member of Project Admin, Collection Admin or Server Admin then remove them or explicitly deny the "manage process template" permission

Comment: Installing it now. Thank you!